# How to completely disable 3 finger tap by any means in libinput

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, libinput

What I want is to be able to just disable 3 finger tap because I never use it and it also messes up what code I write. I use libinput and `synclient` is not an option. I also use `X11` instead of `Wayland`. My goal is to completely disable it. I have been searching for 2 hours now, so finding a duplicate to my question is hard.

Neofetch returns this bit of info if needed

```
OS: Kubuntu 21.04 x86_64
Host: iBall CompBook Marvel6 V3
Kernel: 5.11.0-16-generic
Shell: Bash 5.1.4
DE: Plasma 5.22.4
WM: KWin
```

`xinput list` returns this (Ignore the mouse, I am here for the touchpad device):

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA3602:00 0911:5288 Mouse               id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA3602:00 0911:5288 Touchpad            id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB 2.0 Web Camera: USB 2.0 Web           id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ F&D HW-110 (AVRCP)                        id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Also note that this is a fresh install of Kubuntu

Before any solutions, I would like to notify that gnome-tweaks does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I was not able to fix it. But in plasma 5.22 I found a setting named `Input Devices` -> `Touchpad` -> `Taps` -> `Tap to Click` -> `Three Fingers`. I set it to no action and everything works perfectly as I would have expected.

Here is a screenshot of the setting:
[image: Image of the Settings Menu]

Comment: Looks like this option was eliminated in Kubuntu 22.04. You can swap what two- and three-finger taps do, but not disable them in KDE. This is a real problem for me because I often do them accidentally because I have problems with my right hand.